# actionBarSherlock subtitle textSize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm using ActionBarSherlock subtitles and trying to change the subtitle textsize using styles, but it seems that doesn't work. I'm not that familiar with themes, so.. How can I change that??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.Styled.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.Styled.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.Styled.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```